# Printing numbers with it decreasing but it skipped over something supposed to print

Tags: java

**Instructions**

The game starts when I give you some Teddy bears. You can then give back some bears, but you must follow these rules (where n is the number of bears that you have):

If `n` is even, then you may give back exactly `n/2` bears.
If `n` is divisible by `3` or `4`, then you may multiply the last two digits of `n` and give back this many bears. (By the way, the last digit of `n` is `n%10`, and the next-to-last digit is `((n%100)/10)`.
If `n` is divisible by `5`, then you may give back exactly `42` bears.
The goal of the game is to end up with EXACTLY `42` bears.

For example, suppose that you start with `250` bears. Then you could make these moves:

```
--Start with `250` bears.
--Since `250` is divisible by `5`, you may return `42` of the bears, leaving you with `208` bears.
--Since `208` is even, you may return half of the bears, leaving you with `104` bears.
--Since `104` is even, you may return half of the bears, leaving you with `52` bears.
--Since `52` is divisible by `4`, you may multiply the last two digits (resulting in `10`) and return these `10` bears. This leaves you with `42` bears.
--You have reached the goal!
For each integer `50`, `51`, `52`, ..., `500`, tell me if `42` can be reached and if so, what are the steps. Notice I use a stack to reverse the printout, so it is more readable. For example, the output of the last few cases are shown here:
```

[image]

**This is my code:**

```
import java.util.Stack;

public class Hw18_1
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Stack<String> stack = new Stack<>();

        for (int i = 50; i <= 500; i++)
        {
            System.out.println("\nStarting number:" + i);

            if (bears(stack, i))
            {
                while (!stack.isEmpty())
                    System.out.println(stack.pop());
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("No solution");
            }
        }
    }

    static boolean bears(Stack<String> stack, int n)
    {
        int product;

        if (n == 42)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else if (n < 42)
        {
            // your work
        }
        else if ((n % 2 == 0) && bears(stack, n / 2))
        {
            // your work
        }
        else if ((n % 5 == 0) && bears(stack, n - 42))
        {
            // your work
        }
        else
        {
            product = ((n % 100) / 10) * (n % 10);
            // your work
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: If you tell for which value of n, the solution is to skip printing the result, will speed things up

Comment: Instead of embedding images of output, please copy the text of the output and paste that into the question (formatted).

Comment: What is your question? If your output is incorrect, please put in the expected output.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question was asked a long time ago. But here is the solution for the people who were wondering. (Cause IMO it's a badly worded question without many hints.)

```
import java.util.Stack;

public class Bear {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Stack<String> stack = new Stack<>();
        for (int i = 496; i <= 500; i++) {
            System.out.println("\nStarting number:" + i);
            if (bears(stack, i)) // Checks condition of bool of bears
                while (!stack.isEmpty())
                    System.out.println(stack.pop());
            else
                System.out.println("No solution");
        }
    }

    static boolean bears(Stack<String> stack, int n) {
        int product;
        if (n == 42) {
            return true;
        } else if (n < 42) {
            return false;
        } else if ((n % 2 == 0) && bears(stack, (n / 2))) {
            stack.push("n=" + n + ", return " + (n / 2) + ". Now n=" + (n / 2));
            return true;
        } else if ((n % 5 == 0) && bears(stack, (n - 42))) {
            n -= 42;
            stack.push("n=" + (n + 42) + ", return " + 42 + ". Now n=" + n);
            return true;
        } else { // RULE #2
            product = ((n % 100) / 10) * (n % 10);
            if ((product != 0) && ((n % 3 == 0) || (n % 4 == 0)) && bears(stack, (n - product))) {
                stack.push("n=" + n + ", return " + product + ". Now n=" + (n - product));
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

Hopefully this helps. :D